# Syntax Error when trying to plot data from a CSV uploaded into Google colab

Tags: python, plot, syntax, syntax-error, google-colaboratory

I am running into a syntax error. I am attempting to load a CSV from my local computer into Google colab and then plot the data. This part of the code works fine:

```
uploaded = files.upload()
def plot_csv(filename):

  with open(filename,newline='') as csvfile:
    x=[]
    y=[]
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile) 
    for row in plots:
      x.append(int(float((row[0])))
```

But once I get to this, colab returns an error of "invalid syntax':

```
      y.append(int(float((row[1])))
```

Any thoughts on what the syntax error might be? I have been staring at it for too long.

Thank you!

Comment: You're missing one closing bracket on the end. It should be `y.append(int(float((row[1]))))`

Comment: You see this error because the previous line, appending to `x`, also has this problem.